# Using JNI with kotlin gives UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use JNI with kotlin to use c++ code in kotlin, but for some reason im getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError even though the signature should be alright since its generated using `javah`. Any ideas why it would do that?

Kotlin Function Declaration:

```
external fun initLuaScript(script: String);
```

`javah` generated header:

```
/*
 * Class:     gg_kapilarny_luakt_LuaScript
 * Method:    initLuaScript
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_gg_kapilarny_luakt_LuaScript_initLuaScript
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

C++ definition of the function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_gg_kapilarny_luakt_LuaScript_initLuaScript(JNIEnv* env, jobject self, jstring script) {
    lua_State* l = luaL_newstate();

    const char* cstr = env->GetStringUTFChars(script, nullptr);
    bool result = checkLua(l, luaL_dostring(l, cstr));
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(script, cstr);

    if(!result) {
        std::cout << "LuaKT: Failed to load the script!" << std::endl;
        return;
    } else {
        std::cout << "LuaKT: Successfully loaded the thingy" << std::endl;
    }

    jclass nativeDataClazz = env->FindClass("gg/kapilarny/luakt/NativeData");
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(nativeDataClazz, "nativeData", "Lgg/kapilarny/luakt/NativeData;");
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(nativeDataClazz, "<init>", "(J)V");

    jobject nativeData = env->NewObject(nativeDataClazz, constructor, (jlong) (uintptr_t) l);
    env->SetObjectField(self, fid, nativeData);
}
```

Comment: How about the basics? Is the library compiled for correct CPU architecture, and is it loaded in JVM with the same bitness (32bit/64bit)?

Comment: @JockX It should be. I did the same setup for other functions and those worked earlier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the problem!
The problem was that i did not load the Native DLL. 
Basically i had the library load when the "Main" library class was loaded but i happened to execute a function before the actual DLL load, which caused the error!